# Why doesn't Scheme have loops?

Tags: loops, scheme, lisp

If Scheme comes from Lisp, which is a list programming language, then how come they don't have built-in loops, or are there loops and I'm unaware?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Scheme has loops: tail calls *are* loops.

Comment: Why the `prolog` tag?

Comment: I'm taking a class on scheme and prolog and we are using recursion to iterate through the list. So I just was curious why we had to use recursion for prolog and scheme. Thanks for the quick answer though!

Comment: You probably think you can assimilate Scheme and Prolog on the basis that you know one or perhaps more Algol dialects and I've been there. I though I knew 5 languages but I only knew 5 dialects of Algol. All of them has `while` and `for` loops and I expected every lanague to have that as well.. Turns out it's just an Algol feature. Good luck on learning your 2nd and 3rd programming language!

Comment: For a different perspective, you could also ask the question in reverse: since these other languages I've studied support recursion, why do they also need loops?

Comment: Well isn't fair to say that we have loops for simplicity, just as we have higher level languages to make it easier to program in. So wouldn't it make scheme so much easier to use if there were loops built in?

Comment: With macro, you can define your own loop, or make your own "loop" grammar. I saw people do that, which sucks and uses a lot of structural atoms like `(defmacro loop (variable from lower to upper suite)...)` where you use `loop` with `(loop i from 0 to 10 (progn ...)`. That sucks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why doesn't Scheme have loops?

Because Scheme (and also Ocaml) requires [tail-calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) and the [R5RS](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/) specification requires the Scheme implementation to properly provide them (this is false for Java and C. In C only recent compilers are *sometimes* able to do that tail call optimizations, and most don't).

With tail recursion, you don't need any looping constructs; a tail-call is implemented by a "jump with arguments" so don't push a fresh call frame on the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) (but *replaces* the current call frame with a new one).

> how come they don't have built-in lists,

Scheme has lists.

And Scheme does have loops, but want you to think properly about them and code tail recursive calls. Once you mastered that, you'll see that it is more general and more elegant than looping constructs. Read also about [continuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation) and [CPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style).

I am surprised that so few people ask : why C or C++ has loops? These languages could state that tail-call optimizations are required. The only reason for having loops in a language is lack of tail-call optimization. So C or Java have loops for historical reasons mostly. I guess that Common Lisp has loops mostly for historical reasons too. (the [Common Lisp hyperspec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/index.htm) don't require tail-call optimizations, but all good implementations, such as [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/), provide it).

Comment: But I can use tail recursion in other languges like c and java and they have loops.

Comment: My bad I meant to say built-in loops.

Comment: Most implementation of C and Java don't have tail call optimization. For example, GCC provides it only with `gcc -O2` (and in *some* cases). AFAIK, Java is forbidden to make tail call optimization, since there is no JVM operation for that.

Comment: Ahh ok, so recursion is optimized in scheme so they just don't add loops since they aren't needed?

Comment: No, you need to read about tail calls and call stacks. Not every recursion is tail-recursive

Comment: I vote for having both loops and optional tail-call elimination. Then I can decide which is more natural or elegant.

Comment: @coredump I vote for always having TCO, so I always have a choice.

Answer (score 1):

Scheme has loops (or at least used to have, I am not very up to date on Scheme).

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Scheme_Programming/Looping:

> The 'do' form
>
> There is also an iterative construct, do, which can simplify writing some functions. For example, this procedure sums all the elements of the given list:
>
> ```
> (define (sum/display lst)
>   (do ((remaining lst (cdr remaining))
>        (final-sum 0 (+ final-sum (car remaining))))
>       ((null? remaining) final-sum)
>     (display (car remaining))
>     (newline)))
>
> (sum/display '()) 
> > 0
>
> (sum/display '(1 2 3 7))
> >>> 1
> >>> 2
> >>> 3
> >>> 7
> > 13
> ```

Comment: Note that `do` is not primitive syntax but derived syntax. `do` is turned into a recursive function in a `letrec` by the macro expander and even [documented like that in the report](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-6.html).

Comment: Ok. I had a quick look but couldn't find it.

Comment: You didn't see the `(define-syntax do ...)` in the middle of the page?

Comment: I meant I had a quick look before the first posting, to see if `do` occurred in the report.